# Embedding link preview into a post

Tags: django

I am just wondering how can I embed link previews into my posts in my Django app?
Is embedly the only way to go? as embedly doesnt cover all the websites. Also, if I have to stick with embedly, can I get some links on their API for Django that maybe I can use to make a templatetag?